# Pycharm - cannot import math module

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I have a problem because i can't import math module in pycharm and I need arctan2 function, from IDLE console I can do it and use functions.

When I go to the File/Settings/Project Interpreter section, I have that list:
[image]

When I want to add math package, I cannot found it
[image]

I reinstalled pycharm, and that didn't work for me

pycharm version: 2017.2.3
python version: 3.6.2

What can cause that? What other libraries contain trigonometry functions like arctan2?

Comment: the `math` module does not have to be installed. It is always part of the `python` interpreter. Do you get an error when you go `import math`?

Comment: Yes, in pycharm I have an error, but in python console I don't

Comment: In the dropdown menu of the `interpreter`, are there other entries? `...\AppData\Roaming\Python` seems a strange location for your python folder to me.

Comment: @offeltoffel only that one path

Comment: Still, I don't quite believe that this is your desired location for the interpreter. Next shot: in the console (not in pycharm) try `print (sys.executable)` and check if your `python.exe` is really stored in that folder you have set in PyCharm. You may have to `import sys` beforehand.

Comment: In console I have `pythonw.exe`, in pycharm `python.exe`

Comment: So you could locate your `pythonw.exe` and add it as a local interpreter. Usually `PyCharm` does that automatically, but aparently the pythonpath of your system environment does not match with the one you intend to use with PyCharm. Get your versions sorted and you will be fine.

Comment: That works, you should add an answer, I would choose it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that seemed to work for you:

Choose the same `python.exe` for PyCharm as it's registered in your `PYTHONPATH`variable. If it is not listed, you can add it manually in Settings -> Python Interpreter

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. `(Ctrl + Alt + S)`
2. Click (Project: xxxx),
3. Choose (Project Structure) and select (home / yourUser / PycharmProjects / XXXX / venv / bin) and right-click (Excluded) or `(Alt + E)`.
4. Now click (+ Add Content Root) and see if it points to the following location (/ home / yourUser / PycharmProjects / XXXXX / venv / bin) and click OK.

Now close the IDE and open it again.